# Two pictures side by side but with arrows between them

Tags: tikz-pgf

Can somebody help me to draw something like this:
[image]

What I tried:

```
\documentclass[border={10}]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=10pt,y=10pt,>=stealth, scale=.75]
\draw[fill=white] (-6,4) .. controls (-3,6) and (1,6) .. (3,4) ..
controls (3.5,3.5) and (5,-8) .. (2.5,-10) .. controls (1,-11) and
(-1,-11.5) .. (-4,-11) .. controls (-8,-10) and (-9,-8) .. (-6,4); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=10pt,y=10pt,>=stealth, scale=.75]
\draw[fill=white] (-6,4) .. controls (-3,6) and (1,6) .. (3,4) ..
controls (3.5,3.5) and (5,-8) .. (2.5,-10) .. controls (1,-11) and
(-1,-11.5) .. (-4,-11) .. controls (-8,-10) and (-9,-8) .. (-6,4);
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

These are the two outside contours... I have no idea how to put the arrows or the inside contours.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. In particular, please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) of what have you tried till now.

Comment: Why not make a single image with both images and the arrows?

Comment: Can you say why you want to draw it as two pictures, rather than one? That greatly complicates things to no obvious purpose.

Answer (score 2):

If you need smooth curves, consider using the `Hobby` library.

Not very efficient, but hopefully self-explanatory. I assume you want to draw the internal blobs you need. Here, I just do one arbitrarily and duplicate.

The point is the arrows. The blobs are put in `local bounding box`es so that they can be named. Their anchors are then used to define the start and end points of the arrows.

[image: connected blobs]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=10pt, y=10pt, >=Stealth]
  \draw (-6,4) .. controls (-3,6) and (1,6) .. (3,4) .. controls (3.5,3.5) and (5,-8) .. (2.5,-10) .. controls (1,-11) and (-1,-11.5) .. (-4,-11) .. controls (-8,-10) and (-9,-8) .. cycle;
  \coordinate (a) at (current bounding box.center);
  \scoped[local bounding box=E]{\draw (a) ++(-2,4) [out=80, in=-150] to ++(-.5,1.5) [out=30, in=45] to ++(5,-4) [out=-135, in=10] to ++(-2.5,-2) [out=170, in=-100] to cycle;}
  \begin{scope}[yscale=-1, xscale=-1, local bounding box=A]
    \draw (a) ++(-1,6) [out=80, in=-150] to ++(-.5,1.5) [out=30, in=45] to ++(5,-4) [out=-135, in=10] to ++(-2.5,-2) [out=170, in=-100] to cycle;
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[xshift=150pt, local bounding box=B]
    \draw (-6,4) .. controls (-3,6) and (1,6) .. (3,4) .. controls (3.5,3.5) and (5,-8) .. (2.5,-10) .. controls (1,-11) and (-1,-11.5) .. (-4,-11) .. controls (-8,-10) and (-9,-8) .. cycle;
    \coordinate (b) at ([xshift=150pt]a);
    \scoped[rotate=115, local bounding box=C]{\draw (b) ++(2,-1) [out=80, in=-150] to ++(-.5,1.5) [out=30, in=45] to ++(5,-4) [out=-135, in=10] to ++(-2.5,-2) [out=170, in=-100] to cycle;}
    \begin{scope}[yscale=1, xscale=-1, rotate=160, local bounding box=D]
      \draw (b) ++(-1,6) [out=80, in=-150] to ++(-.5,1.5) [out=30, in=45] to ++(5,-4) [out=-135, in=10] to ++(-2.5,-2) [out=170, in=-100] to cycle;
    \end{scope}
  \end{scope}
  \draw  (A.center) [bend left, ->] to (D.center);
  \draw  (E.center) [bend right, ->] to (C.center);
  \draw  (E.north east)  [bend left, ->] to (C.west |- E.north);
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```